# Sending SMS and Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

In My Application User Can Set Alarms. Some Alarms for Itself and Some for Who he want To Send SMS. But My Problem is The Alarm not Works Properly in Some Phones And also if Its Works Good its not Sending SMS
this is my AlarmService Class:

```
 @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    setAlarm();

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

private void setAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Cursor cursor = G.drugsDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM drugs", null);
    long startDate;
    String number;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("drug_id"));
        startDate = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("start_date"));
        String patientName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("patient_name"));
        number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("drug_receiver"));
        String drugNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("drug_count"));
        String unit = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("drug_unit"));
        String drugType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("drug_type"));
        String drugName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("drug_name"));

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(G.context, ShowAlarmActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myIntent.putExtra("PATIENT_NAME", patientName);
        myIntent.putExtra("NUMBER",number);
        myIntent.putExtra("DRUG_NUMBER",drugNumber);
        myIntent.putExtra("UNIT",unit);
        myIntent.putExtra("TYPE",drugType);
        myIntent.putExtra("NAME",drugName);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - 5000 > startDate) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            continue;
        }
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startDate, pendingIntent);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

and this is My ShowAlarmActivity class:

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String number = "";
    String patientName = "";
    String drugCount = "";
    String drugType = "";
    String unit = "";
    String drugName = "";

    if (bundle !=null ){
        patientName=bundle.getString("PATIENT_NAME");
        number = bundle.getString("NUMBER");
        drugCount = bundle.getString("DRUG_NUMBER");
        drugName = bundle.getString("NAME");
        drugType = bundle.getString("TYPE");
        unit = bundle.getString("UNIT");
    }

    Log.i("LOG", "Number is : " + number);
    if (number !=null && number.length() > 5){
        sendMessage(number,"یادآوری می شود"+patientName+" "+drugCount+" "+" "+unit+" از "+drugType+" " + drugName+ " الان مصرف نماید. \n خداوند شفابخش و مهربان است.");
        ShowAlarmActivity.this.finish();
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String destination,String message){
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    int length = message.length();
    if(length > 160) {
        ArrayList<String> messageList = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(destination, null, messageList, null, null);
    }
    else {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(destination, null, message, null, null);
    }
    Toast.makeText(G.context,"پیام با موفقیت ارسال شد",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("LOG","Message Sent");
}
```

and I Should Notice That in My Country Phone Numbers is Like : 0919837xxxx

Comment: Did you set the SMS permission in the AndroidManifest? And did you test the sending SMS by itself without the alarm?

Comment: Yes I set permission and for the second no i dont test it

Comment: It is not a good programming practice to combine multiple components together then trying to test them. Test the Sending SMS first then integrate it with the Alarm function

Comment: I tested it and its ok but in code above i dont know whats wrong